# Codeception doesn't provide exception information when tests fail

Tags: rest, exception, laravel, codeception

I use Codeception with REST and Laravel modules.

When I run `vendor/bin/codeception run` and tests fail because of an exception, no information is being displayed in the command line other than the test has FAILed.

So I know that *something* is wrong, but don't know what *exactly* is wrong.

Some more detail:

1. When test expectation isn't met, the error message is being displayed just fine (e.g. I expect the result to be JSON but it's in fact HTML)
2. On the contrary, if there's an exception, Codeception just returns `FAIL` and "swallows" the exception details.

Please note that these exceptions are *catchable*, not fatal errors as was suggested in the answer, so I don't understand why Codeception is not able to display the error message properly.

To find what is the exact problem, I have two options:

1. Wrap the test with a try-catch block (so I catch and debug everything manually)
2. Manually make an HTTP request and see the output

Obviously, both "solutions" are unacceptable.

Am I missing something and is there a solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the test framework just don't have access to the information, because the application framework is not providing them. Fatal errors may "abnormal end" your app, giving no clue to whom is expecting a simple exception in return.

What I just to do in those cases is to look at the log files:

```
/var/www/myapp/app/storage/logs/laravel.log

/var/log/nginx/*.log
```

Comment: Hi Antonio. Thank you for the reply.

But doesn't this violate the whole idea of TDD? How can I write tests before code if tests do not provide information on how to make them green?

BTW, the example with database exception is not a fatal error (I can even catch this exception by hand in my tests)

Comment: Yeah, but if you, for example, violates the operating system (memory, disk, file permissions, webserver configuration...), there's nothing your tool can do for you, unfortunatelly those "rules" doesn't work every single time. :)